# Is there an estimation about the monetary conseuqences of the distrust of the markets caused by the freeze of the Russian assets?

Tags: banking, russia

I think already the news of the frozen Russian assets (and the possibility of its nationalization to the Ukrainian government) caused some distrust on the market. If the probability of that the bank does not give your money back as you want, increases, then the probability that you put your money elsewhere, increases with it.

Thus, distrust has monetary consequences. Maybe it is not impossible, that these consequences might be more serious as the original sum was.

Does some estimation exist about it? What might be the amount of the money which were not put into the Western back sector because the freeze? What might be its price (in the form of missed profit on it)?

Comment: In principle it’s possible to estimate what you are asking for, but in order to estimate the effect you need to have a lot of data after the event occurred. In 2024 we do not even have final values (i.e. values that are unlikely to be revised in the future) for GDP in 2022. In fact, it was only around 2020 that papers about the 2014 sanctions (after annexation of Crimea) started to pop up, so you will have to wait at least probably another 4 years before we get some early estimates, and maybe a decade for more comprehensive estimates.